# Solve the never ending linux (and of course, ubuntu) suspend/standby problems?

Tags: kernel, suspend, dell, power-management, standby

OK, So this is not going to be my best SE question, and may even violate guidelines for questions, however... In recent months this has become such a massive PITA in my everyday work flow, that I am going to post such a difficult to answer question. I suggest to gather evidence here in comments of actual solutions that **WORKED FOR YOU**.

I'm also torn between superuser and askubuntu as research shows this is not an ubuntu specific problem. If there is a real problem with use of this platform to create such a go-to solution page for this wide ranging problem, then feel free to close. I'm also aware of the similar issues and while I can see it as a good idea to link them, please do not flag as "duplicate".

*I never would have imagined how much not having standby gets in the way of work until having to live with it. And I know, from research that there are many out there in the same boat.*

So, The "TL;DR" actual "question"

**My (Dell Latitude 5590) laptop will not suspend reliably. Can you help fix this?**

Data points.

- Attempting to enter standby, whether it be via pm-suspend, systemctl or ubuntu menus results in a blank screen, any external USB disks spin down and the power LED remaining on. Nothing brings the laptop back to life other than a hard reset.
- Standy works with the windows 10 that came with the laptop (which is shrunk and never used)
- The bios is the latest available from Dell.
- It used to work with Ubuntu 16 some years ago. (I do not have data on actual kernel version at that time)
- Standby works *sometimes*, let's say about 10% of the time.
- Disabling networking before attempting to standby increases this percentage.
- A plethora of kernel versions, and kernel and module arguments and combinations of those that can be found out there have been tried but as yet nothing found that makes standby work reliably.

Research summary:

- Research shows many reports of replicas or similar with laptops, not limited to Dell Latitudes.
- There are reports blaming the video driver. (i915) However, no reliable solution.
- There are reports blaming the BIOS (however, see above "works with the shipped OS")

My conclusion:

Support for standby on many laptops is currently severely broken in the linux kernel and has been so for some time.

Comment: The `pm-tools` package might help.

Comment: Did you mean `pm-utils`? And if so, please expand. Please add comments that explain clearly personal experience in actually solving the problem. 
To be clear, pm-suspend, as I mentioned above, also locks up the laptop.

Comment: System error messages at the time of suspend would be helpful.

Comment: Indeed, Thanks, and you are right. However, getting system error messages after the system hang is more complicated. At which point does it hang and did it flush to disk before that is a question....